# Is there a way to parse data from multiple pages from a parent webpage?

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I have been going to a website to get NDC codes https://ndclist.com/?s=Solifenacin and I need to get 10 digit NDC codes, but on the current webpage there is only 8 digit NDC codes shown like this picture below

[image: 8 digit NDC code]

So I click on the underlined NDC  code. And get this webpage.

[image: 10 digit NDC code]

So I copy and paste these 2 NDC codes to an excel sheet, and repeat the process for the rest of the codes on the first webpage I've shown. But this process takes a good bit of time, and was wondering if there was a library in Python that could copy and paste the 10 digit NDC codes for me or store them in a list and then I could print the list once I'm finished with all the 8 digit NDC codes on the first page. Would BeautifulSoup work or is there a better library to achieve this process?

EDIT <<<< 
I actually need to go another level deep and I've been trying to figure it out, but I've been failing, apparently the last level of webpage is this dumb html table, and I only need one element of the table. Here is the last webpage after you click on the 2nd level codes. 
[image: last level page]

Here is the code that I have, but it's returning a tr and None object once I run it.

```
url ='https://ndclist.com/?s=Trospium'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for a in soup.select('[data-title="NDC"] a[href]'):
    link_url = a['href']
    print('Processin link {}...'.format(link_url))

    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link_url).content, 'html.parser')
    for b in soup2.select('#product-packages a'):
        link_url2 = b['href']
        print('Processing link {}... '.format(link_url2))
        soup3 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link_url2).content, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup3.findAll('tr', limit=7)[1]:
            print(link.name)
            all_data.append(link.name)

print('Trospium')
print(all_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, BeautifulSoup is ideal in this case. This script will print all 10 digits codes from the page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ndclist.com/?s=Solifenacin'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for a in soup.select('[data-title="NDC"] a[href]'):
    link_url = a['href']
    print('Processin link {}...'.format(link_url))

    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link_url).content, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup2.select('#product-packages a'):
        print(link.text)
        all_data.append(link.text)

# In all_data you have all codes, uncoment to print them:
# print(all_data)
```

Prints:

```
Processin link https://ndclist.com/ndc/0093-5263...
0093-5263-56
0093-5263-98
Processin link https://ndclist.com/ndc/0093-5264...
0093-5264-56
0093-5264-98
Processin link https://ndclist.com/ndc/0591-3796...
0591-3796-19
Processin link https://ndclist.com/ndc/27241-037...
27241-037-03
27241-037-09

... and so on.
```

EDIT: (Version where I get the description too):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://ndclist.com/?s=Solifenacin'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

all_data = []
for a in soup.select('[data-title="NDC"] a[href]'):
    link_url = a['href']
    print('Processin link {}...'.format(link_url))

    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link_url).content, 'html.parser')
    for code, desc in zip(soup2.select('a > h4'), soup2.select('a + p.gi-1x')):
        code = code.get_text(strip=True).split(maxsplit=1)[-1]
        desc = desc.get_text(strip=True).split(maxsplit=2)[-1]
        print(code, desc)
        all_data.append((code, desc))

# in all_data you have all codes:
# print(all_data)
```

Prints:

```
Processin link https://ndclist.com/ndc/0093-5263...
0093-5263-56 30 TABLET, FILM COATED in 1 BOTTLE
0093-5263-98 90 TABLET, FILM COATED in 1 BOTTLE
Processin link https://ndclist.com/ndc/0093-5264...
0093-5264-56 30 TABLET, FILM COATED in 1 BOTTLE
0093-5264-98 90 TABLET, FILM COATED in 1 BOTTLE
Processin link https://ndclist.com/ndc/0591-3796...
0591-3796-19 90 TABLET, FILM COATED in 1 BOTTLE

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej,  I didn't know where to start, cause this is the first time I looked into parsing, and I was thinking Beautiful Soup could do the job but I was thinking it may not because of the jumping forth between the two pages. Thanks a lot, this will save me a good bit of tedious work!

Comment: @Alex No problem... I added to my answer a version where I get the description too alongside the code. Hope it helps!

Comment: Also Andrej, when you use BeautifulSoup do you just inspect html to determine what to grab (like how you determine link_url and #product-packages a' ) or is there a different way? And is this website the best site for documentation of beautifulSoup? https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: @Alex Yes, I use the same documentation. I use Firefox developer tools for inspecting elements and network requests ( Chrome has something similar too ).

Comment: Sweet, thanks I actually prefer Firefox so that's great, thanks again for answering all my questions!

Comment: Andrej I was wondering if you could help me out again, I actually need to go another level deep. I noticed I was pulling 10 digit NDC codes but I needed the 11-digit NDC codes. I'll edit the question above. Because apparently it's too long here.

Comment: @alex rather thanks editing there question here, open a new one. It will keep things more clear.

Comment: Thanks Andrej, the new question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801700/how-to-select-a-specific-row-from-a-table-using-beautifulsoup